# PHP returning extra line returns

Tags: php, post

When posting from JS, PHP (5.3.8) returns some line returns in excess. For example:

```
if (isset($_POST['postId']) && $_POST['postId'] == "test") { 
    echo 'ok';
}
```

returns `ok↵↵↵`

Is this by design? How can I get rid of those line returns?

Comment: Is there anything after the echo statement in the code? You might try putting `die();` immediately after the echo. Also, could you post a sample of the JS that you're using?

Comment: Can you look into the page HTML source and check how are the extra return being displayed? Are they in <p> tag or extra <div> or <br/> ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not by design. You have three newline output.

Try to delete the close tag of php `?>`, if you don't have any html after php code.

Another way is just put `exit;` right after `echo`, you won't get newline again.

Comment: of course... I had the extra returns after the php close tag in a very long file. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

... right below your

```
echo 'ok';
```

paste another snippet:

```
echo '--------new line------';
```

if the gap (extra returns) show between your first echo and the -----new line----- it would be more than strange:)  However if it shows below the ------new line----- you have probably some extra HTML text (tags) below your PHP statement.